# Why does this calculation return -Infinity?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I need to do a few simple subtraction calculations in my script, however it is not quite so simple as it turns out, what am I doing wrong here?

```
x= dbo.collection("master").find({Process: "Process1"}).toArray(); //Query my Mongo database
s1 = Math.max.apply(null, x.map(o => o.NumberInt)); //narrow down query to find the correct number 
s2 = (s1-1); //minus 1 from the result to find next result
//s2 returns -Infinity
```

I am 100% sure that `s1` is an integer

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(s1)` to double check that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox its in the comment, i needed it to narrow down the query

Comment: Also probably `console.log(x.length)` while you're at it. If you call `Math.max` with no arguments (so if `x` is length 0) you get `-Infinity` back.

Comment: @Pointy yes s1 is definitely an integer

Comment: We only have your word for it ;)

Comment: Well if `s1` is definitely an integer, what integer is it?  If you log it you'll actually know the answer.

Comment: @Pointy `s1` is 2495

Comment: If `s1` is 2495, then s2 would be 2494. Your computer is probably not broken. People are suggesting you add `console.log()` statements to *verify* what you believe to be true.

Comment: With the code shown and the value of `s1` as 2495 there is *no way* `s2` is `-Infinity`. Something is not as you describe!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this calculation return -Infinity?

It's easy enough to check the conditions where `Math.max.apply(null, input)` could return `Infinity` or `-Infinity`

```js
function  doTheMagic(input){
    return Math.max.apply(null, input);
}


console.log(doTheMagic([1,2]));
console.log(doTheMagic(["1","2"]));
console.log(doTheMagic([null, undefined]));
console.log(doTheMagic([Infinity]));
console.log(doTheMagic(null));
console.log(doTheMagic({}));
console.log(doTheMagic([]));
```

`-Infinity` comes about wherever you have a null, an empty array or a blank object - and there may be a few others too. These are the most likely outcomes from your code.

I would go out on a limb and suggest your `x.map(o => o.NumberInt)` is returning an empty array.

Comment: I think you are correct, this was only a small portion of the code...i think my issue is much wider. Due to the synchronous nature of JS it is running this part of the code before my database has updated (so at this point the database is blank). Cheers anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you supply a parameter that is not a number (or cannot be coerced to a number) then the result will be `NaN`

`Math.max` will only return `-Infinity` when it is called without any parameters.

```js
console.log(Math.max()); // -Infinity
console.log(Math.max(1)); // 1
console.log(Math.max("")); // 0 (coerced to 0)
console.log(Math.max({})); // NaN (not a number)
```

But you are using `Math.max.apply(null, x.map(o => o.NumberInt));`.
If the second parameter of `Function#apply` is not iteratable then no arguments will be passed to `Math.max` which is the same as having an empty array.

To check if an object is iteratable you can use the following expression:

```
if (typeof x[Symbol.iterator] === "function")
    console.log("I am iteratable.");
```

In conclusion, `x` is either empty or a not iteratable object.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yeah, forgot about `Function#apply` only accepting iteratable objects. Updated the answer.